# how to resolve submit_arrival permission error with orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I've created a 'Content type' with 3 sets of radio buttons. Then used this content type as a form to be accessed from the main menu by a new user.

Once the user has signed up and their account is approved by an administrator they can login and view the form. Trouble is when I try this with a new user I get the error message:

```
Cannot create content. Current user, p@p.com, does not have Submit_arrival permission.
```

I've went through the content type and form but see no options for submit_arrival permission.

Any ideas?
Ta

Comment: You may need to give the authenticated user permission to create your content type. Go to users, roles, edit them there

Comment: ok....So im clicking on 'users' which navigates to Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Users/Views/Admin/index.cshtml which throws an error: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: linkText with the @Html.ActionLink(entry.User.UserName, "Edit", new { entry.User.Id })

Comment: as this is a new issue i put up a question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/askhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @Hazza thanks again. i had to give the authenticated user permissions. much appreciated